# UIDocumentPicker function for under IOS.14

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm beginner in Swift. I have made a document picker at my task. But I see the documentation it was deprecated to used `open var documentPickerMode: UIDocumentPickerMode { get }`. While the project in my task runs with minimum deployment of IOS13. [image: here;s the ScreenShot image description here]

Is there a solution for this feature that can be used on IOS14 and below? Or is this normal, where users need to update IOS?. Forgive me for my ignorance, as I'm new to swift world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

...you'll see the list of four initializers introduced in iOS 14. Each one configures the picker for one specific type of task. There is no need for a "mode" because you cannot *not* know how your picker is configured, because *you* configured it. That is the modern architecture.

At the bottom of the same page you will see the three deprecated initializers from iOS 13 and before, each of which takes a "mode" as a parameter. That is what you must use if you insist upon supporting iOS 13, even though they are deprecated in later systems. And that's fine. "Deprecated" means discouraged and superseded; it does not mean illegal. What you're getting is just a warning, not (as your title wrongly stated) an error.

Answer (score -1):

just try this one code

```
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    guard url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
        return
    }
    defer { url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
    var error: NSError? = nil
    NSFileCoordinator().coordinate(readingItemAt: url, error: &error) { (url) in
        let _ : [URLResourceKey] = [.nameKey, .isDirectoryKey]
        let documentFileData = NSData(contentsOf: (url)) as Data?
        pickImageCallback?(nil, url.lastPathComponent, documentFileData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.